# Building HTML table

Tags: jquery, append

I'm building a table from a JSON object.  First step is to build the table column headers:

```
jq_tblRow = $('<tr>') ;
obj_Report.fieldMetadata.forEach( function(elt) {
   jq_tblRow.append('<th>' + elt.name)
}) ;
```

That yields a row with the column headers:

```
<tr><th>Item Type</th><th>Title</th> ... etc... </tr>
```

Is there an easier way to wrap that with TABLE & THEAD tags?  Here's what I came up with eventually.  It works but 2 calls to ".append()" seems awkward.

```
jq_tblRow = $('<table>').append( $('<thead>').append(jq_tblRow) );
```

I tried various combinations of

```
 .append('<table><thead>')
```

using append, appendTo, prepend, before, after, etc and the permutations thereof.

Comment: There are other methods that could do the same thing but it all fits into a one liner...how much simpler would you expect it to get?

Comment: Do note however that `jq_tblRow` is now actually the whole table not the row you appended...not sure what that assignment is intended for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a jQuery element, you can use the [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to wrap it with some additional tags :

```
jq_tblRow = $('<tr>') ;
obj_Report.fieldMetadata.forEach( function(elt) {
    jq_tblRow.append('<th>' + elt.name)
});
// After you have your row in the DOM, wrap it with table/thead tags
jq_tblRow.wrap('<table><thead></thead></table>');
```

The `wrap()` function can also accept a function, if you need to handle more complex operations or preferred the look of concatenating each side :

```
jq_tblRow.wrap(function(){
     return '<table><thead>' + this.innerHTML + '/thead></table>';
});
```

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks!